# Why do we need stateless widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

As the below diagram shows `Stateful widget` covers what `Stateless widget` do, When I can do the same thing with `Stateful widget`, why Flutter designers added another widget? For increasing performance?
Please do not post the difference just answer the Why?

[image]

Comment: Sometimes, all you need is a view, and not a viewmodel as well.

Answer (score 6):

Would you always use a sword to do a knife's job? Given that you always have both of them available with easy access. The knife can't do everything a sword can, but would that mean that a sword should be used by default for everything, since it's more robust?

You'll have many widgets where the state of the elements will not change, and others where you will not have to use `setState` to update your UI either(given that you would rather not use higher level state management solutions).

Using stateless widgets as long as they can do the job, means more performent widget trees.

> Please do not post the difference just answer the Why?

Knowing the difference between them is key to understanding 'why', and the differences are not just in the name `less` vs `full`. But sensing that you aren't interested, that's why.

Answer (score 2):

Good Flutter code seperates the code into many small Widgets. In addition to better performance creating a StatefulWidget means that you have to write more code and add unnecessary complexity to your code.

Answer (score 1):

For better performance. Stateless widgets are usually only called in one of these three situations:
1- widget is inserted in the tree.
2- Widget's parent changes its configuration
3- Inherited Widget it depends on changes.